# How Number objects print the value in java?

Tags: java, string, overriding

```
Integer myInt = new Integer(10);
System.out.println(myInt);
```

This would give me back 10. But how? Every time I print out for example a custom Number object, which has a value, or any other object I get back something like: `com.example.CustomNumber@14ae5a6`

How can I achieve, to get the value as a number? Shall I Override something? I get it how it works with Strings, I'd simply override the toString method, but how does it work with numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *This would give me back 10. But how?*

Integer class overrides the **toString** Method which is returning the int value of the object as String (that is what the System.out.println is receiving as parameter)

Exactly code of the ToString()

```
public String toString() {
    return toString(value);
}


public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

to avoid this: **com.example.CustomNumber@14ae5a6**

you have to override the toString method and give something meaningfull for what is that for an object instead of the default hashcode...

Answer (score 3):

> Shall I Override something?

Yes. As you said, you should override the `toString()` method.

> How does it work with numbers?

The `Integer` class has simply overriden the `toString()` method, and thus, when calling `println(myInt)` this override get executed.